# Scala data structures: chain of operations (such as mapValues, filter ...) and intermediate results

Tags: scala

Consider the following:

```
val stuff = Map[String, Int]("apple" -> 5, "orange" -> 1, "banana" -> 3, "kiwi" -> 2)

val used = 1

val rest = stuff.mapValues{
  case quantity => quantity - used
}.filterNot{
  case (fruit, quantity) => quantity == 0
}
```

The result is

```
rest : scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(apple -> 4, banana -> 2, kiwi -> 1)
```

Although I'm not an expert in Scala, I know that the language is not lazy (differently from Haskell), so `mapValues` will produce an intermediate `Map`, which in turn will be passed as input to `filterNot` (and so if there were other operations in chain).

How to avoid this useless intermediate data structures?

Note: I understand that the question can be generalized to other data structures. Here I'm using a `Map` just be cause it's the data structure that I was using in my real code (although with other data :) )

Comment: I would not deem it useless; clearly it has a use. You maty find the `collect` method handy for situations like this. It combines `map` and `filter` using a partial function (cases not handled by the PF are filtered out) and this is more parsimonious both in source code and internal data structures.

Comment: @RandallSchulz I thought about `collect`, but I didn't figure out how to use it in my example. Could you please transform your comment into an answer and show me how to? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
object  ChainOpsRS
{
  val stuff = Map[String, Int]("apple" -> 5, "orange" -> 1, "banana" -> 3, "kiwi" -> 2)

  val used = 1

  val rest =
    stuff.collect {
      case (fruit, quantity) if quantity > used => (fruit, quantity - used)
    }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    printf("stuff=%s%n", stuff.mkString("{", ", ", "}"))
    printf(" rest=%s%n", rest.mkString("{", ", ", "}"))
  }
}
```

When run it produces this output:

```
stuff={apple -> 5, orange -> 1, banana -> 3, kiwi -> 2}
 rest={apple -> 4, banana -> 2, kiwi -> 1}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `view` method of any collection class to create a view of the collection that will apply methods like `map` and `filter` lazily. See http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.collection.TraversableLike

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Kim's answer, it should be noted that the `mapValues` method actually does *not* compute intermediate results: `mapValues` returns a *view* of a Map.  This makes it different from most other methods including `filterNot` or even `map`.

An example:

```
val rest = stuff.mapValues {
  case quantity =>
    println("reading quantity " + quantity)
    quantity - used
}

rest("apple")
rest("apple")
```

prints:

```
reading quantity 5
reading quantity 5
```

Comment: interesting! I didn't notice that `mapValues` was already returning a `view` ... This is also a little confusing ... why does `mapValues` behaves differently?